# Error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in tests after execute mvn clean:install

Tags: java, maven, classnotfoundexception

In my console execute `mvn clean:install -Dmaven.test.skip=true` and my project runs okay.

But if I try to write a new test or run an existent one, I get  `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.

To fix it in Eclipse I must right click in my project -> properties -> Java compiler -> Compiler compliance level and there change the Java version so the `.class` files get generated again.

--EDIT.--

Thank you for your attention, my question is, how to recreate the classes again so i can run my tests without the right click -> etc -> etc.

And yes, it is  **mvn clean install** not  ***mvn clean:install***

Comment: Are you asking how to prevent the error in the first place?

Comment: Are you sure that is `mvn clean:install` and not `mvn clean install`? Also, do you have several profiles in your pom.xml?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I added some more details, tank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, maven clears all compiled class files. So, you get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` and other missing class errors.
To fix,
In your Eclipse, `right-click on project, Maven - Update Project...`
Click `OK` and wait until maven compiles you Java project again.

[image]

Comment: It worked fine, just as you said. but i'm still wondering how to avoid this intermediate step, i also tried to run clean install with the eclipse tools, right click -> Run as -> Run configurations -> and add my own configuration with goals: clean install and checked: skip tests but the result is the same .

Comment: Why do you need to `clean`?

Comment: What i really need is to install and create the .jar (component) to be used by my web app. but sometimes if clean is not executed, not all the changes are reflected in the web. in the beginning of my project i used to run only install but in some point i noticed that the .jar created was not taken all the changes. (sorry if i am repetitive).

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't. I've tried several ways, but no one works.